# Positive and negative magnetostriction

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

We had the experiment demonstrating magnetostriction. We used interferometer to detect any length changes. We put the ferromagnetic material inside a coil and apply axial field.

While telling about positive and negative magnetostriction, we are told that if you consider some ferromagnetic material to be made of ellipsoid domains, then on applying magnetic field, these domains align either along or antiparallel to the magnetic field. If they align along the field, it generates a tensile stress which leads to increase in length while the other case produces negative magnetostriction.

My question is, that since magnetic domains contains both magnetic poles, why would there be any stress in the axial direction (the direction in which field is applied).

Also I would like to know how one would know about the shape of domains (or it was just for demonstration purposes).